SQL Data Migration Assistant fails to produce deployment script due to Triggers
I'm trying to use the Microsoft Data Migration Assistant to migrate my SQL Server DB to SQL Azure.
I have a Delete trigger which references the DELETED pseudo table. When the assistant tries to generate the deployment script, I get the following error

An unexpected error occurred.
The Default '[dbo].[Deleted]' does not exist on the server.

From what I understand and what I have observed, SQL Azure has support for triggers. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Is it a bug with the Data Migration Assistant?

The pseudo tabledeleted is not a member of a schema, you should not be prefacing it withdbo.

Hi @DaleK my trigger only references deleted and not [dbo].[Deleted]. DMA seems to be trying to translate deleted to [dbo].[Deleted]

That's kinda critical info, please add to your question.

DMA is a deprecated tool already, but I do love DMA because is the easiest way to migrate to Azure SQL.
As a workaround, if I were you, I would create a copy of the database by restoring from backup, I would script that trigger then drop it from the restored database. I would perform the assessment again against the restored database, if everything is OK, I would proceed to do the migration to Azure SQL with the DMA Tool. Once the migration is finished, I would use the script to create the trigger on the Azure SQL Database.
The supported tool is currently Azure SQL Migration Extension on Azure Data Studio.
